# Prove that the order of $10$ modulo $ 59$ is greater than $30$ without calculating powers of $ 10$ mod $59$ directly.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the order of $10$ modulo $59 $ is greater than $30 $ without calculating powers of $ 10$ mod $59$ directly. My thought is using Fermat's theorem $10^{58}=1 \bmod(59)$, and the order of $10$ mod $59$ divides $58$. It's easy to prove $10^2$ is not $1$ mod $59$, but I have a hard time proving $10^{29}$ is not $1$ mod $59$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can you use quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: I can't cobble anything together, but I notice that it's easy to get $2^7 \equiv 10$.  Also $5^3 \equiv 7$, so $5^6\equiv 49 \equiv -10.$   Maybe those will help?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show that $10^{29}\equiv-1\bmod59$ if you know quadratic reciprocity.

By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), $10^{29}\equiv\left(\dfrac{10}{59}\right)\bmod59$.

Now $\left(\dfrac{10}{59}\right)=\left(\dfrac5{59}\right)\left(\dfrac2{59}\right)$.

By quadratic reciprocity (since $5\equiv1\bmod4$), $\left(\dfrac5{59}\right)=\left(\dfrac{59}5\right)=\left(\dfrac45\right)=1,$

and $\left(\dfrac2{59}\right)=-1$, because $59\equiv3\bmod8$.

Can you take it from here?